# Painting a ListView with correct answer?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a List questions in this list there are 4 questions, 3 false and 1 true. I created a Bean to control these questions, the bean has an attribute value, this attribute receive 1 or 0, 1 to true and 0 to false.

When user click in a question on ListView I want to check if question has value=1 or value=0, if value=0 I want to paint all value=0 with color red and if value=1 paint with color green, showing that question is true !

How can I do it ?

Here how I'm trying.

```
//bean
public class Bean{
    private int value;
    //get and sets
}


//activity
List<Bean> answers = new ArrayList<Bean>();
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.answers_listview);
listView.setAdapter(new BeanListAdapter(context, answers));


//ListAdapter
public class BeanListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Bean> lista;
    private Context context;    

    public BeanListAdapter(Context context, List<Bean> lista){
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;        
    }   

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        Bean item = lista.get(position);
        View layout;
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alternativa_list_adapter, parent, false);            
        }else{
            layout = view;
        }
        LinearLayout llAlternativa = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.llAlternativa);
        TextView tvAlternativa = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvAlternativa);

        if(item.getValue() >= 1){
            llAlternativa.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#529c03"));
            tvAlternativa.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }else{        
            llAlternativa.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d74b3f"));
            tvAlternativa.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }   


        tvAlternativa.setText(item.getTexto());        

        return layout;
    }

}


@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Bean answer = listAnswers.get(position);
            LinearLayout llAlternativa = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.llAlternativa);
            TextView tvAlternativa = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvAlternativa);
            if(answer.getValor() == 1){
                //green
                llAlternativa.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#529c03"));
                tvAlternativa.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }else{
                //red
                for(Bean x : listAnswers){
                    if(x.getValor() == 0){                      
                        llAlternativa.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d74b3f"));
                        tvAlternativa.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    }
                }               
            }


    }
```

Comment: Does the user need to do any Click? Where is that onClick Method? Because from your getView method, I would think, the background color is already set without any user interaction. Or do I miss something?

Comment: yep, user need a click. When user click in: `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` the background is changed with red or green depending of value 1 or 0

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by this: "but when I click in option ListView does not paint the lines with colors."

Comment: so, I'm have a question, this question has 4 answer. I displayed these questions in ListView. To 4 questions i have one true and others false. If user select value true, the line of ListView need paint green and others paint red, can you understand ?

Comment: Now I understand. Could you post your onItemClick Method? I would surround your if else statement (to change color) in your getView Method with another if statement (`if (userHasChosen)`). Then in your onItemClick Method change the boolean userHasChosen to true and notify your adapter (`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`) - If you don't understand this I write this as an answer more precisely

Comment: @Wicked161089 I posted onItemClick !

Comment: hei @Wicked161089, I did your suggestion and now works. I created a control boolean variable in my Adapter with name `change`. When user click in onItemClick I send value true to this variable and change with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Wicked161089 can you create an answer to I do check V ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would surround your if else statement (to change color) in your getView Method with another if statement (`if (userHasChosen)`). Then in your onItemClick Method change the boolean userHasChosen to true and notify your adapter (`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`)

```
 if(userHasChosen){     // GETVIEW     
    if(item.getValue() >= 1){
        llAlternativa.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#529c03"));
        tvAlternativa.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }else{        
        llAlternativa.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d74b3f"));
        tvAlternativa.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }   
 }
```

And in your onItemClick:

```
  userHasChosen = true;
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```